# CODA: How can I save as a file through ftp?

Tags: coda

In CODA editor, is there **Save as remote copy** like other editors?

Answer (score 1):

I found:

With a remote connection established
Just FILE > NEW FILE  (command + option + N) Will create a new file on remote host directly instead to create a file (command +N) in local computer.

After that just rename file in left panel.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean save the remote copy of a file to your local machine then simply make sure the file browser pane is open (View > Show File Browser), then click on the Remote tab, find the file you want to save and select "Download to 'your computer name'".